# netbeans email server related to drupal

Tags: drupal, netbeans

i'm working with a drupal website that uses netbeans on apache for windows, so deployed through glassfish.
everytime i try send an email i get the message:

> Unable to send e-mail. Please contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

the company which sold us the server, also gave us the mail server (mirodinero.com is the website). what i don't understand is that we have set on the netbeans project a different server (in configurationproperties of netbeans, it's smtp.mirotele.com), while we have

`POP server: mail.mirodinero.com`
`SMTP server: smtp.mirodinero.com`
`IMAP server: mail.mirodinero.com`

which one shall i put instead of smtp.mirotele.com?

then, still in configuration properties, it asks me for a user and password for the email. where shall i search for these data? shouldn't be the company to give me the necessary data?

Answer (score 0):

To send email with authentication via SMTP, you'll need the PHPMailer or SMTP module. As far as I know, they do the same thing. And yes, your provider **should definitely** provide you login information for your SMTP server. Otherwise it would risk becoming an open relay (a server used by spammers).

1. http://drupal.org/project/phpmailer
2. http://drupal.org/project/smtp

Comment: ok, i fixed the smtp module thanks to your advice, and now at least drupal sends notification emails, like changing password, etc.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i fixed the smtp module thanks to your advice, and now at least drupal sends notification emails, like changing password, etc. what is not working now is the contact form, i get this message looking at the dblog of drupal:

`Error sending e-mail from cl----e@mirodinero.com to st---s@hotmail.it : Error SMTP: Los siguientes destinatarios fallaron: stokks@hotmail.it

SMTP server error: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user bed513c`

what is the problem now? i searched on the internet and i haven't found a solution, because for example bed513c is the actual user of cl----e@mirodinero.com, that i set up in the smtp module administration page.